# Remove Indentation on TreeViewItems in Firemonkey XE5

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to remove all indentations on a TreeView in Firemonkey so that a TreeView will display as a flat list regardless of the parent child relationships within the treeview.

I've had a look at the stylebook and there's nothing there that looks like it sets the indentation depth.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: as far as i know, its more like hardcoded inside. Better use a listbox or grid.

Comment: If that's what you want, a TreeView is probably the wrong control to use. Perhaps a ListView, ListBox, or Grid would be a better choice. A tree clearly indicates parent/child relationships.

Comment: @Ken White.  No A treeview would be the correct control.  I wish to indicate the parent/child relationships in another way and so require a flat list of a Treeview.  Sounds like it can't be done though.

Comment: @user2125574:  You might find it easier to handle representing the parent/child hierarchy of the data separately from handling its display.  E.g. construct a tree of nodes to represent the hierarchy and then use one of the visual controls Ken White suggests to display them.

Comment: Separate the data from the visual in this case. Use a listbox to display it visually and multidimensional array(s) to hold the actual data. That way you maintain the relationships in the data but achieve the visual design you want.

Comment: "I wish to indicate the parent/child relationships in another way". You would perhaps get better answers if you explained this other way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this in XE6 (I haven't tested this in XE5 but I assume it's the same).  Set up a custom style for your items in your stylebook (or use treeviewitemstyle if you want this to apply to all treeviews), add a TLayout (or any control) as a child of the style, give it a StyleName of "expander", set the Visible property to False and make the width of 0.  Apply and close the style designer, then set the StyleLookup of all your TreeViewItems to your custom style and the indent will disappear.